# Http failure response 501: Not implemented, altought the exact same method works on web

Tags: ios, iphone, http, ionic-framework, cross-domain

I am currently building an ionic app, and deploying a development version on my iphone 5s. I deploy the exact same version that I deploy on my web browser. The version on the web browser works perfectly fine and does not show any errors.

However, when I run the app on my physical iphone 5s, I get the following error:

```
Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/get-preferences: 501 Not Implemented
```

This error is the result of the following function:

```
//Logs that 'body' and 'this.headers' are correctly created

await this.http.post('/get-preferences', body, {headers: this.headers})
.toPromise().then(data => {

      //Logs everything as a correct result on web
      //The following line is what displays the above error through XCode through the iphone.

    }).catch(err => console.log("Error getPreferences occured: ", (<Error>err).message));
}
```

I googled a little bit, and adding proxies to the `ionic.config.json` should have solved this for both web and iphone, but somehow the phone version does not work correctly.

This is the contents of my `ionic.config.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ionic2-app-base",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/get-preferences",
      "proxyUrl": "http://serverIp/get-preferences"
    },
    {
      "path": "/register-vote",
      "proxyUrl": "http:/serverIp/register-vote"
    },
    {
      "path": "/create-user",
      "proxyUrl": "http://serverIp/create-user"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anything more I have to have enabled on the iphone, such that this 
 works?

I am using the `import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';` modules for the post request.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

I think you try to access the API from the emulator (ios / android) with an address htt: // localhost: 8080 / ... or http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ...

It's normal that it does not work localhost is the phone (even  emulated).

Solution : Change your api url localhost with the ip address of your pc/server example: 192.168.xx.xx